# she needs looking after vs she needs to be looked after

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, phrasal-verbs

Put the verb into the correct form.

> My grandmother isn't able to look after herself any more. She needs _______ (look) after.

Does "She needs looking after" and "She needs to be looked after" mean the same thing?

Source: English Grammar in Use by Raymond Murphy, Unit 57

Comment: Colloquially, yes, they're equivalent.

Comment: Verb + gerund is OK in British English. 'Wants' is possible too. _`Your hair wants cutting,' said the Hatter. He had been looking at Alice for some time with great curiosity, and this was his first speech._ Alice's Adventures in Wonderland, Lewis Carroll.